# Remove "message" field for metricbeat set data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, metricbeat

I am trying to get metricbeat data using logstash. 
(Kafka as input & ElasticSearch as Output).

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "XX.XX.XXX.XX:9092"
    topics => ["cc-data"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["XX.XX.XXX.XX:9200"]
    index => "metricbeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

In the output I see the data as :

```
     {
        "_index" : "metricbeat-2017.01.18",
        "_type" : "logs",
        "_id" : "AVmzQUytyldhSr4kUaUS",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "@timestamp" : "2017-01-18T20:21:45.324Z",
          "@version" : "1",
          "message" : "{\"@timestamp\":\"2017-01-18T20:21:44.394Z\",\"beat\":{\"hostname\":\"ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX\",\"name\":\"ip-XX-XXX-XX-XXX\",\"version\":\"5.0.0\"},\"metricset\":{\"module\":\"system\",\"name\":\"process\",\"rtt\":104061},\"system\":{\"process\":{\"cpu\":{\"start_time\":\"2016-08-03T10:10:17.000Z\",\"total\":{\"pct\":0.000000}},\"fd\":{\"limit\":{\"hard\":4096,\"soft\":1024},\"open\":0},\"memory\":{\"rss\":{\"bytes\":0,\"pct\":0.000000},\"share\":0,\"size\":0},\"name\":\"migration/2\",\"pgid\":0,\"pid\":47,\"ppid\":2,\"state\":\"sleeping\",\"username\":\"root\"}},\"type\":\"metricsets\"}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I do not want "message" FIELD alone.. Instead, all the datas in that field should appear as it is [want to remove the "message" field name alone - but the content of that should appear] How do I delete the field name alone, and keep the content as it is.

Can anyone help how do we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `kafka` input has a `plain` codec by default, which means that it consumers the topic and interpret the content as a plain string. What you need instead is to change the codec to `json` to it parses the content to a JSON structure:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "XX.XX.XXX.XX:9092"
    topics => ["cc-data"]
    codec => "json"           # <---- add this
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Val, here is the error I am getting - [2017-01-19T05:22:48,052][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"metricbeat-2017.01.19", :_type=>"metricsets", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-01-19T04:45:04.733Z %{host} %{message}], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"metricbeat-2017.01.19", "_type"=>"metricsets", "_id"=>"AVm1MKLZyldhSr4khi3q", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [system.process.cpu.start_time]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception"

Comment: It is metricbeat data.

Comment: That's a different issue now and the sign that it's is now parsing your `message` field as JSON correctly. Can you update your question with the output you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_template` and `curl -XGET localhost:9200/metricbeat-2017.01.19` ?

Comment: template is too long to attach. I have updated the question with metricbeat.yml file and logstash configuration ... From metricbeat -> pushing data to Kafka topic 'cc-data', and in Logstash configuration -> Reading the input data from Kafka topic 'cc-data' and push the output to ElasticSearch. I do not want logstash default fields. I am looking for the data how we used to see when we push from metricbeat -> Elasticsearch...